# Electron Return Value to Renderer form Main

Tags: javascript, electron

I have the below code that does a database query, it returns the rows and I see the rows in console.log. However, in the renderer process I do not get the returned rows, console.log shows 'undefined'. Am I missing something?

Main.js

```
exports.accounts = function() {

    db.serialize(function() {
        db.all("select * from accounts", function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                return rows;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

app.js (renderer)

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
const main = remote.require('./main.js');
$scope.accounts = main.accounts();
console.log($scope.accounts);
```

Comment: Have a look at Electron IPC https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md